# Simple implementation of merge sort in javascript

Tags: javascript, mergesort

What's wrong with following implementation of merge sort algorithm. it just returns **undefined**.

I suspect the error is somewhere in merge function.

can someone help me point out the error.

```
    function mergeSort(arr1, lower, higher) {

    if (lower < higher) {
        var mid = Math.floor((lower + higher) / 2);
        mergeSort(arr1, lower, mid);
        mergeSort(arr1, mid + 1, higher);
        merge(arr1, lower, mid, higher);
    }
}
```

And merge function

```
function merge(arr1, lower, mid, higher) {

    var i = lower;
    var j = mid + 1;
    var k = 0;
    var mergearr = [];

    while (i < j && j <= higher) {

        if (arr1[i] <= arr1[j]) {
            mergearr[k] = arr1[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        } else {
            mergearr[k] = arr1[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }

    }

    if (i === j) {
        while (j < higher) {
            mergearr[k] = arr1[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    } else if (j > higher) {
        while (i < j) {
            mergearr[k] = arr1[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    }


    for (var a = 0; a <= k; a++) {
        console.log(a);
        arr1[a] = mergearr[a];
        console.log(arr1[a]);
    }

    return arr1;
}
```

Here is output on the console

```
index: 0
 value: 4
index: 1
 value: 5
index: 2
 value: 4
index: 3
 value: undefined
index: 0
 value: 4
index: 1
 value: 4
index: 2
 value: 5
index: 3
 value: 4
index: 4
 value: undefined
index: 0
 value: undefined
index: 1
 value: 4
index: 2
 value: undefined
index: 3
 value: undefined
index: 0
```

Comment: You don't `return` anything in your `mergeSort` function.

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside possible "off-by-1" errors in the sort, the `merge()` function has a problem in the way that it copies the merged list back to the source array. The function is told to merge from `lower` to `higher`, which it does. But then, the merged array is copied back to the original array **starting at index 0**. Instead, you need to make sure that the original array is only modified between `lower` and `higher`:

```
for (var a = 0; a <= k; a++) {
    console.log(a);
    arr1[a + lower] = mergearr[a]; // <--- here
    console.log(arr1[a + lower]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could tweak your code. Yes, the problem was with your `merge()` function. Take a look:

- you don't need to return anything from `merge()` since this value
  isn't used anywhere.
- `a` should start from `lower` which is incremented every time in
  order to avoid rewriting already sorted part of the array
- your construction to pick up odd indexes` values was weird and
  bloating
- also you messed up indexes at the beginning of the function

```js
var arr = [5,3,7,8,1,2,6,3,2];

mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
console.log(arr);

function mergeSort(arr, lower, higher) {
  if (lower < higher) {
        var mid = Math.floor((lower + higher) / 2);
        mergeSort(arr, lower, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, higher);
        merge(arr, lower, mid, higher);
  }
}

function merge(arr, lower, mid, higher) {
    var l = mid-lower+1, r = higher-mid, k = lower, mergearr = [], i = 0, j = 0;

    while (i < l && j < r) {
        if (arr[lower+i] <= arr[mid+j+1]) {
            mergearr[k] = arr[lower+i]; i++;
        } else {
            mergearr[k] = arr[mid+j+1]; j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (j < r) {
      mergearr[k] = arr[mid+j+1]; k++; j++;
    }
    while (i < l) {
      mergearr[k] = arr[lower+i]; k++; i++;
    }
    //console.log(mergearr, k, lower);
  for (var a = lower; a < k; a++) {
    arr[a] = mergearr[a];
    } 
}
```